# pandas groupby(col).nunique() return NaN

Tags: python, pandas

In a DataFrame with 2 columns `chain_id` and `chain_event_id`, I'm trying to create a third one that counts unique values of `chain_event_id` within each `chain_id` group. For instance, if `chain_id` number 511 has three rows with `chain_event_id` values `1,2,1` I expect that new column to hold the value 2.

Consider this sample data set:

```
 d = {'chain_id': [511,511,511,666],'chain_event_id':[1,2,1,1]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I tried using

```
df['events_in_chain'] = df.groupby('chain_id').chain_event_id.nunique()
```

as well as `.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))` and `.agg('nunique')` but the result is the same: Each group gets all NaN values.

The printout for this piece of code:

```
    import pandas as pd

    d = {'chain_id': [511,511,511,666],'chain_event_id':[1,2,1,1]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    print(df)
    print(df[df['chain_id'] == 511][['chain_id', 'chain_event_id']])
    print(df[df['chain_id'] == 511]['chain_event_id'].unique())
    print(df[df['chain_id'] == 511]['chain_event_id'].nunique())
    df['events_in_chain'] = df.groupby('chain_id').chain_event_id.nunique()
    print(df[df['chain_id'] == 511]['events_in_chain'])
```

is this:

```
   chain_id  chain_event_id
0       511               1
1       511               2
2       511               1
3       666               1
   chain_id  chain_event_id
0       511               1
1       511               2
2       511               1
[1 2]
2
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
Name: events_in_chain, dtype: float64
```

Why is `events_in_chain` getting `NaN` and not 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create a new column with the nunique per group, so you need to use `transform('nunique')`:

```
df['events_in_chain'] = df.groupby('chain_id')['chain_event_id'].transform('nunique')
```

Output:

```
   chain_id  chain_event_id  events_in_chain
0       511               1                2
1       511               2                2
2       511               1                2
3       666               1                1
```

Comment: Yup, it worked. Why did transforms do the trick?

Comment: If you `apply` or `nunique` you get 1 row per group. See it as an aggregation procedure. With `transform` you expand the result to the original shape (1 value per original row in the group)